# How to print value in nested json format using python

Tags: python, json, amazon-cloudwatch

Here is my code :

```
if m.namespace in metric_config.keys():
 for d in m.dimensions.keys():
  if d == metric_config[m.namespace]["dimension"]:
    if m.name in metric_config[m.namespace]["metrics"].keys():
      if len(metric_config[m.namespace]["metrics"][m.name]) > 0:
        metric["Namespace"] = m.namespace
        metric["MetricName"] = m.name
        dimension["Value"] = m.dimensions[d][0]
        metric["Statistics"] = metric_config[m.namespace]["metrics"][m.name][0]

if metric != {} and dimension != {}:
  cwatch_config["metrics"].append(metric)
  cwatch_config['Dimensions'].append(dimension)
```

This code is not printing dimension in metric column and I want to print it in required format as below mention.

```
"metricsConfig": {
  "metrics": [
  {
    "Namespace": "AWS/RDS",
    "Statistics": [
      "Average"
    ],
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

}

Comment: I don't see any print statements in the code. You may like to use `pprint`, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

Comment: I dump my result in json format but this code doesn't print

Answer (score 0):

If you have parsed your data into a JSON object `j`, then you can convert it to a JSON string using [`json.dumps(j)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps). The optional `indent` parameter allows you to specify how nested elements should be formatted:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(j, indent=2))
{
  "metricsConfig": {
    "metrics": [
      {
        "Namespace": "AWS/RDS",
        "Statistics": [
          "Average"
        ],
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you mean to say abovi code is working and print result as required.

Comment: I already use print json.dumps(cwatch_config,indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')) but didn't get result